# Where can I find a programmer/game developer to team up with?

Tags: software-engineering, pixel

I'm a pixel artist looking for an ametuer programmer/game developer to team up with, But I'm not sure where to start!

I'm not particularly worried about profit, I'm only interested in making the game as a hobby.
Where can I find potential partners?

Comment: There's not really a *correct* answer to this question, so I don't think it fits the site. I suggest you try gamedev.net, specifically the job boards: http://www.gamedev.net/classifieds/category/2-contractors/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Show What You Can Do**

When looking to start or join a team online, people are always interested in seeing what work you've produced beforehand. The work doesn't necessarily have to be done in a game, but it should showcase your ability to create game quality assets.

**Talk About What You Want To Do**

If you're looking to recruit people for a team, talk about the project you're wanting to work on. You don't have to have all the details fleshed out, but it is important that potential applicants understand the scale and scope of work you're wanting to accomplish. As an example, there is a big difference in the programming skill and amount of effort required to produce an [Astroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_%28video_game%29) clone and a [Bullet Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_%27em_up#Types) style game with online networking capabilities.

**Read and Follow The Rules**

A lot of communities that have job/recruitment boards have specific rules about posting in them. In many cases, they require you to fill out a template when posting, to help ensure you hit on all the major pitch points. Be sure to read the rules for each site before you post.

**Resources**

Here are links to a few communities you may find useful for recruiting game developer talent:

- GameDev.net Hobbyist:
  http://www.gamedev.net/classifieds/category/5-hobbyist-projects/
- IndieDB Recruiting:
  http://www.indiedb.com/forum/board/recruiting-resumes
- ModDB
  Recruiting: http://www.moddb.com/forum/board/recruiting-resumes
- TIGSource Unpaid Work: http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?board=41.0