# Where can a game developer/programmer get freelance jobs?

Tags: software-engineering, jobs

I'm a game programmer looking for freelance jobs online. I know that there are lots of sites for freelance jobs, but I haven't been lucky with them, I was wondering, which sites are the best for looking for jobs? I know that Freelance.com and upwork.com are some of them, but they ask a lot of profile information and, although I complete it, added a portfolio and have a low hourly rate price for starting (and, by the way, what would be an ideal hourly rate for a starter?) I can't get any jobs because the vicious cycle of not having reputation in the site because I'm not hired because I don't have reputation...

So, resuming the question: *What would be the best sites/way to get a freelance job as a Game Programmer through the web?*

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for lists of resources, such as places to find jobs, aren't on-topic here; you may want to ask on [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) instead.

Comment: And check out this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37503/where-can-i-find-a-programmer-game-developer-to-team-up-with